# Entity Framework | Code First | Mapping of sub property from CultureInfo.Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mapping, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I've got an entity like this :

```
public class Course {
    public CultureInfo Culture {get; set;}
    :
}
```

And I want to map just the `Name` property of `CultureInfo` to a single column in the table that Entity Framework generates for me.

How would I go about this? Currently I've tried looking at the OnModelCreating() method of the DbContext, but I'm not finding anything that is standing out.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 in and MVC 3 application with a Code First approach.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfrotunatelly EF can't do it this way. The workaround is defining separate property with the `Name` which will be mapped to the database and marking your `Culture` property as not mapped.

```
public class Course
{
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
    public string CultureName 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Cuture != null)
            {
                return Culture.Name;
            }

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            // same check for value can be placed here

            Culture = new CultureInfo(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And in mapping you will define:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .Ignore(c => c.Culture);
```

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but we can't have everything I suppose :) Thanks very much Ladislav!