# Map properties of type CultureInfo

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

My domain model contains properties of both types `CultureInfo` and `IList<CultureInfo>`.  How can I map these to the database?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684094/entity-framework-code-first-mapping-of-sub-property-from-cultureinfo-name

Answer (score 0):

They simply can't be mapped directly because no database supports those types so you will have to create another type in your domain model (probably a Complex Object) that holds the properties of CultureInfo you are interested in or the second option would be to store the type in the database as binary data and for this you can convert CultureInfo to a stream of bytes, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653095/how-to-store-images-using-entity-framework-code-first-ctp-5) for more info.