# Mapping .NET types to a database using the Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using the `CultureInfo` class to describe the language of localizable data in my application.

```
class LocalizedText
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public CultureInfo Language { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'd like to map the above class to a database table, using a code first approach.

Sample data:

> ```
>  +----+------------------------+----------+
>  | Id | Text                   | Language |
>  +----+------------------------+----------+
>  |  1 | Hello World!           | en       |
>  +----+------------------------+----------+
>  |  1 | Hallo Welt!            | de       |
>  +----+------------------------+----------+
>  |  1 | Bonjour tout le monde! | fr       |
>  +----+------------------------+----------+
> ```

I thought this would be easy enough to do using the Fluent API in EF6, but I guess it's not.

What I've tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CultureInfo>()
            .HasKey(info => info.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
```

But then I get an error. Presumably because `CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` is read-only.

> The key component 'TwoLetterISOLanguageName' is not a declared
>   property on type 'CultureInfo'. Verify that it has not been explicitly
>   excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

So can this be done at all?

Comment: To confirm your suspicions: yes, this is because it is readonly. When retrieving the data from the database and populating your object, it will need to be able to set that property.

Comment: But it can be set through a constructor overload like this: `new CultureInfo("en")`. Is EF too dumb to figure this out?

Comment: I'd argue that the complexity required for EF to figure out assignments in constructors and their possible side-effects, are simply too complicated and feasible to do. You will need to [work around it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684094/entity-framework-code-first-mapping-of-sub-property-from-cultureinfo-name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map `CultureInfo` class to column in database. But you can ignore this property and create another string property which will be mapped:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocalizedText>()
    .Ignore(lt => lt.Language);

modelBuilder.Entity<LocalizedText>()
    .Property(lt => lt.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
    .HasColumnName("Language");
```

And then just set `Language` property when `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` is assigned:

```
public class LocalizedText
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo Language { get; set; }

    public string TwoLetterISOLanguageName
    {
      get { return Language == null ? null : Language.TwoLetterISOLanguageName; }
      set { Language = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear :/ I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately EF will not allow you to pass field value to some specific constructor of `CultureInfo` and then read some specific property when writing field back. Even if there was no problem with identity, it's just too complex and rarely required to be implemented in ORM. If you have mapping between entities stored in database and some domain/dto classes, then you can put this logic to data mapper.